# how to check if MobileElement is displayed on screen

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, native

This is the code

```
for (loopVal = 1; loopVal < endVal; loopVal++) {

    MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    String followOrNot = followButton.getText();
    System.out.println(followOrNot + " " + loopVal);
}
```

If MobileElement`followButton` is not found, then it throws an error and the rest of the code will not be executed

I need to check if `followButton` is present before my program runs `.getText()` on `followButton`

If I try to surround `followButton` with a try-catch block

```
try {

    MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    } catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {

        //handle error

    }
```

Then i get an error on `String followOrNot.getText()` that says

> followButton cannot be resolved

If I try to use .isEmpty on `followButton`

```
        MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    if(driver.findElements(followButton).isEmpty()) {

        //handle error
    }
```

Then I get an error on `findElements` that says

> The method findElements(By) in the type AppiumDriver is not applicable for the arguments (MobileElement)

if i try to use `.isDisplayed` on `followButton`

```
        MobileElement followButton = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']"));

    if(followButton.isDisplayed()) {

        //do nothing

    } else {

        //handle error

    }
```

then the problem now would be that if `followButton` is not found an error would be thrown deeming the rest of the code useless

all im trying to is validate the presence of `followButton` before any other operation is performed on `followButton`

I asked a question similar to this one but received no helpful answers, my only option is to ask again.

can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the element is present on the page by first fetching the list of that element and then checking the list size. If the size is greater than zero then the element is present else it is not present.
You can do it like:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']")).size()>0){
// Element is present
// Do the operations here
}
else{
// Element is not present
}
```

Comment: Cannot cast from int to MobileElement

Comment: @dam1ne have edited my answer, please check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. It is working for me.

Declare a Mobile element.

```
MobileElement followButton=(MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']”));
```

Function to check existence of element

```
public boolean checkMobileElementExist(MobileElement element)  {
    boolean objectExist = false;
    try {
        objectExist =element.isDisplayed();

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return objectExist;
}
```

Now use it

```
  If(checkMobileElementExist(followButton))

       {
    // Do your stuff
    }
```

**Another approach - Using list size of elements**

```
List<MobileElement> followButtons=(List<MobileElement>)driver.findElements(By.xpath(“//android.widget.ListView[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='"+loopVal+"']//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']//android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='2']//android.widget.TextView[@index='0']”));


     If(!followButtons.isEmpty())

           {
        // Do your stuff
        }
```

Comment: cannot convert from MobileElement to List<MobileElement>

Comment: Can you try first? meanwhile I can check second

Comment: @dam1ne  sorry my mistake as i am typing everything by mobile so i missed to list of mobile element. I have edited the question. Please try it now. I hope it should work.

Comment: @dam1ne  can you please try now and let me know